# Fragmentstateadapter in viewpager2 not showing Fragment in Navigation Architecture Component

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner, android-viewpager2, android-chips

I use Navigation architecture component - One Activity Many Fragment Style. In ProfileEditHolderFragment, I want to show a list of Fragment in a swappable way using latest ViewPager2 and FragmentStateAdapter. I implemented it like bellow.

`ProfileEditHolderFragment.kt`

```
class ProfileEditHolderFragment : BaseFragment() {

    override fun getLayoutResId() = R.layout.fragment_profile_edit_holder

    override fun initWidget() {
        profile_state_progress_bar.setStateDescriptionData(arrayOf("Tuition", "Education", "Personal", "Credential", "Quiz"))

        val listOfFragment = listOf<Fragment>(TuitionInfoFragment(), EditEducationFragment())
        profile_edit_view_pager.adapter = activity?.let {
            TutorProfileEditAdapter(it, listOfFragment)
        }
    }

}
```

`fragment_profile_edit_holder.xml`

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.fragment.tutorPanel.profileEdit.ProfileEditHolderFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <another view>

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/profile_edit_view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_state_progress_bar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

`TutorProfileEditAdapter.kt`

```
class TutorProfileEditAdapter(
    activity: FragmentActivity,
    private val fragmentList: List<Fragment>
): FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {

    override fun getItemCount() = fragmentList.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int) = fragmentList[position]

}
```

But the problem is no Fragments are shown in ViewPager2 holder.

Comment: I think you must add a screenshot of the navigation scenario that youre trying to show.. 

(1) in the first xml layout, try changong the width/height from 'match_parent' to '0dp'
(2)  ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwihiADN-0k

Answer (score 1):

Try to use childFragmentManager instead of activity